# Android Youtube API HQ mode make video bigger

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to play video from youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi-AImV09q0. I am using Youtube Player to play video but it have some problems.
This video is bigger than real video (on web) so I just only see a part of video. However,if I turn off HQ mode - with lower quality, this video work fine.
This problem also happens in Youtube App. I'm testing with Samsung S2 device
Anyone can give me some advice? Thank in advance

Comment: The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi-AImV09q0) cannot play on web you provide, can you check?

Comment: @bjiang I'm sure that this video is still working on web

Comment: This video is no longer available because the YouTube account associated with this video has been terminated.